# Going to directory using bash variables doesn't work when directory names have spaces

Tags: linux, bash, cygwin

Let's say I want to store the following command in a variable

```
cd "/cygdrive/c/Program Files/"
```

So I do this

```
dir="cd \"/cygdrive/c/Program Files/\""
```

That should store the command to navigate to the Program Files directory, so when I type $dir it takes me to that directory. To check that the quotations have been properly escaped, I type

```
echo $dir
```

which gives me

```
cd "/cygdrive/c/Program Files/"
```

So everything should be working fine. However, when I type,

```
$dir
```

I get

```
bash: cd: "/cygdrive/c/Program: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm using Cygwin, but I assume this problem applies to bash in general.

Comment: Try removing the quotes around the directory name and escape the space with a backslash instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: see [BashFAQ #050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) ("I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!").

Long answer: when bash parses a command, it parses quotes before it replaces variables; it never goes back and re-parses quotes in the values of variables, so they wind up not doing anything useful.  Using echo to check the command is completely misleading because it shows the command *after* it's been parsed; if you want to see what's really being executed use either `set -x` to have the shell print commands as they're executed, or use `printf "%q " $dir; echo` instead of plain echo.

If you want to store a complex command (i.e. one with spaces or other special characters in the "words"), you need to put it in an array instead of a simple text variable, and then expand it with the idiom `"${array[@]}", like this:

```
dir=(cd "/cygdrive/c/Program Files/")
"${dir[@]}"
```

Now, if the purpose is to make an easy-to-type shorthand, this is clearly not the way to go.  Use a shell alias or function instead:

```
alias dir='cd "/cygdrive/c/Program Files/"'
dir
```

or

```
dir() { cd "/cygdrive/c/Program Files/"; }
dir
```

Answer (score 7):

When bash expands `$dir`, it only performs word splitting and globbing on it. Word splitting produces three words: `cd`, `"/cygdrive/c/Program` and `Files/"`. Then the command to execute is `cd` with two arguments; `cd` only looks at its first argument, `"/cygdrive/c/Program`, which is not an existing directory.

If you want to perform full shell evaluation on the content of a variable, use `eval`:

```
eval "$dir"
```

Note that you need the double quotes around `$dir`, otherwise word splitting would first be performed, then `eval` would concatenate its arguments with spaces. This would happen to work here, but would go bad in general (e.g. if there were two consecutive spaces in a file name).

However, a string is not the right way to store a shell command that you want to execute. Unless you have an unusual requirement, you should be using a function instead:

```
dir () {
  cd "/cygdrive/c/Program Files/"
}
```

If you are really interested in typing `$dir` to switch to a particular directory and this isn't just a simple example, since bash 4, put `shopt -s autocd` in your `.bashrc` and set

```
dir="/cygdrive/c/Program Files/"
```

after which you can type just `"/cygdrive/c/Program Files/"` or `"$dir"` at the shell prompt to switch to that directory. You still need the double quotes around `$dir`; if you don't like that, use zsh instead of bash.

Answer (score 6):

Storing commands in variables is generally not a good idea.  That's what functions and aliases are for.

Rather than

```
dir="cd \"/cygdrive/c/Program Files/\""
```

try one of these:

```
dir="/cygdrive/c/Program Files"
...
cd "$dir"
```

or

```
dir() { cd "/cygdrive/c/Program Files"; }
dir
```

or

```
alias dir='cd "/tmp/Program Files"'
...
dir
```

The first form, storing the name of the directory in a variable, means a little more typing, but it's clearer when you execute the command that you're doing a `cd`.  The second is closest to what you're trying to accomplish.  (I don't use aliases much in bash; I'm not actually sure what advantage they have over functions.)

**EDIT :**

And `dir` is probably a bad name for an alias or function, since there's an existing command by that name (it's basically a version of `ls`, at least if you have GNU coreutils).

Comment: upvote for *`Storing commands in variables is generally not a good idea. That's what functions and aliases are for.`*

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
bash$ echo  'This   is   "a     long"  line' > mylist
bash$ echo @mylist
@mylist
bash$ cmd
c:\> c:\cygwin\bin\echo @mylist
This is a     long line
```

But even more specifically:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334467/cygwin-using-a-path-variable-containing-a-windows-path-with-a-space-in-it