# passing quoted arguments to node via shell script?

Tags: bash, node.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Going to directory using bash variables doesn't work when directory names have spaces](https://superuser.com/questions/359297/going-to-directory-using-bash-variables-doesnt-work-when-directory-names-have-s)

I have a text file where each line is a list of arguments I want to pass to a nodejs script. Here's an example file, file.txt:

```
"This is the first argument" "This is the second argument"
```

For demonstration's sake, the node script is simply:

```
console.log(process.argv.slice(2));
```

I want to run this node script for every line in the text file, so I made this bash script, run.sh:

```
while read line; do
    node script.js $line
done < file.txt
```

When I run this bash script, this is what I get:

```
$ ./run.sh 
[ '"This',
  'is',
  'the',
  'first',
  'argument"',
  '"This',
  'is',
  'the',
  'second',
  'argument"' ]
```

But when I just run the node script directly I get the expected output:

```
$ node script.js "This is the first argument" "This is the second argument"
[ 'This is the first argument',
  'This is the second argument' ]
```

What's going on here? Is there a more node-ish way to do this?

Comment: This is regular bash behaviour. It doesn't interpret quotes as delimiters when not read from a command line or shell script. Look into eval, or a different way to store your arguments.